# When does getPlaces() of class google.maps.places.SearchBox return more than one place?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, google-places, google-api-js-client

I am using the Google Map Javascript API v3 and also the google.maps.places.Searchbox class so the user can get to the place he is looking for.

As I saw the [example code of Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

searchBox.getPlaces() is an array and can return more than one place. But as I tried more than once the Places Searchbox I never got more than one place.

So in which case does the searchBox find more than one place?

I am considering to ignore Searches which deliver more than one place because in my use case (find shops nearby in one place) it has to be just one place. But for this reason I wanted to know when it is the fact that the searchbox delivers more than one place as I didn't provoke this and could not find any documentation about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Results that return multiple matches like "coffee" or "mcdonalds".